# Access pipeline variables in Azure Release for classic python task

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-releases

I have a Python script that has url, token, location, and version as environment variables. I trigger it using the **classic Python task**. I declared these variables inside the pipeline variables section, and inside the code, I did the following:

```
import os

os.environ['url']
os.environ['token']
```

but I get `keyerror: 'url'`

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73609993/azure-release-pipeline-environment-variables-on-python-script), which creates a variable group and passes the environment variables as arguments. But this step follows inline script based execution.

[image: Task classic python]

The variables `url` and `token` are marked as secret for the purpose of sharing them here.

[image: Pipeline Variables]

Comment: Please post the pipeline snippet. How are you setting these env variables?

Comment: the env varibales are defined in the variables section under pipeline variables, attached the image to question for your reference

Answer (score 0):

To access pipeline variables from Release pipeline into classic task, we can import them by passing them as arguments.

In .py script

```
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]
token = sys.argv[2]

print(url, token)
```

in arguments we pass the following `$(URL)` and `$(TOKEN)` without spaces.